# HTML table dynamic height for one cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablelayout

Is it possible to have a table that distributes the cell heights like the following?

```
______________________________________
|            fixed height            |
|____________________________________|
|                                    |
|                                    |
|           dynamic height           |
|                                    |
|____________________________________|
|            fixed height            |
|____________________________________|
```

So the height of the first and the last cells are fixed, the center cell should be **dynamic and scrollable**.

Currently I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
<table style="max-height:200px">
    <tr>
        <td height="30px">First element</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Div for scroll functionality if content is too high -->
            <div style="overflow:auto">
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30px">last element</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT: it doesn't need to be a table it is just important that the center element has a dynamic height and is scrollable

EDIT: I know that I can specify the height of the element to be scrolled - then it works. But I want the height of the element to be dynamic

Comment: First of all there is nothing like `scroll:auto;` it is `overflow:auto;`, secondly you must specify height for it to which if encountered scroll is available after.

Comment: @divy3993 Yes of course, my mistake :-)

Comment: @divy3993 Sorry I don't understand... for what do I need to specify the height? Isn't it enough when i specify the height of the root element (in this case the table)?

Comment: I mentioned height not the width.

Comment: Also what do you mean by dynamic? Are you trying to say is, it will have **no specific `height`** and will depend on content. If middle one have more content than it height will increase auto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want this:

**1)** I gave `height:auto` to table, and here `width:80%` to table is optional.

**2)** The `Div` inside `td` is given `height:60px;`(just random to bring up scroll-bar), along with `overflow:auto;`.

**3)** The first and second `td's` have specific `height:30px;`

Check this out:

```html
<table style="height:auto; width:80%;" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td height="30px">First element</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Div for scroll functionality if content is too high -->
            <div style="overflow:auto; height: 60px;">
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30px">last element</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Update : No Specific Height**

Here in a update i used `max-height`

```html
<table style="height:auto; width:75%; margin:0px auto;" border=1>
    <tr>
        <td height="30px">First element</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- Div for scroll functionality if content is too high -->
            <div style="overflow:auto; max-height:100px;">
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
                Dynamic content which needs to be scrolled sometimes
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30px">last element</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> **Note:** If you want to use `%` for `max-height` give `height` and `width` equals `100%` to your `body`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem with this is that you explicitly specified the height of the element to be scrolled. But as explained it should be dynamic. I will make the question more clear

Comment: First thing **FORGET width**, aren't we talking about height?

Comment: Secondly i specified height to bring `scroll-bar`, if you do not specify height to any div, scroll-bar would **never** needed. Because you didn't specify height so `div` would automatically get height such that all content fits in.

Comment: OK I understand... I thought it could work with something like `max-height:100%`... So the answer of my question is that it is not possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93538/discussion-between-divy3993-and-thomas-sparber).